# Linked to id(hash), detecting the hash, but scrollTo not firing through if statement with fixed nav

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with linking to divs and dealing with a fixed header. The header creeps over the div and I can't seem to get it to scroll up 162 px (the size of the header) to show the full div. Apologies if this is a stupid question but I wasn't able to find a solution that works for me after looking through searches for the last half hour.

This is the link users are given.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(location.hash);
    if (window.location.hash){
        $location = $(document).scrollTop();
        console.log($location);
        $location = $location-162;
        console.log($location);
        window.scrollTo(0, $location);
    }
)};
```

This worked with hashchange, but hashchange won't work on a page load.

Comment: Please set up a jsfiddle and post the link

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you mix window and $(document). So your correct script needs to be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log(location.hash);
    if (window.location.hash){
        $location = $(document).scrollTop();
        console.log($location);
        $location = $location-162;
        console.log($location);
        $(document).scrollTop($location);
    }
)};
```

**EDIT:** Now with correct function scrollTop() and only one parameter.

Comment: Oh and like in my Edit now: You're using the function scrollTop(), not the plugin scrollTo(), and this only expects one parameter.